# what is the best way to track unique visitors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, statistics, tracking

what i want is to make user counter as true as possible.
exluding bots, and clever users as much as possible.
as 4 what i know, it can be done in several ways:

- ip (trouble with dinamic ones and proxy's)
- cookies (with session id maybe, but can be deleted or browser can be changed)
- flash cookies (not all users have it)

any other ways? and what is the best?

Comment: I would really save yourself the bother and just use an off-the-shelf package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google analytics to get that data (at least for Google anyway)...

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: unfortunately i need something more than only tracking visits. it's a way of referer system, based on vistis by someone...

so i need a little more than only statistics.  i need to retrieve refer identifier for example a QueryString like


http://mydomain/somepage?refer=someone


maybe it could be done by google via api tools...
or biult-in funtions any one aware of theese thing?
P.S. it uses only cookies again, and it's really easy to cheat...